# Single source for IBM i and z/OS

Tags: ibm-midrange, cobol, zos

I am primarily a C developer, not a regular COBOL developer. I would like my COBOL program to have the same source on IBM-i as it does on z/OS.

My COBOL program calls a subroutine. On z/OS I do the call like this:

```
CALL                                      
  'PBFNInit' USING                        
                    BY VALUE NULL-POINTER,
```

On IBM i I have to call like this:

```
    CALL PROCEDURE
      'PBFNInit' USING                        
                        BY VALUE NULL-POINTER,
```

Is there some way I can dynamically tell the COBOL compiler which format of the CALL statement to use?

I was hoping for some kind of dynamic statement like the debug statement controlled by this

`SOURCE-COMPUTER. IBM-3270 WITH DEBUGGING MODE.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your compiler supports [conditional compilation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cobol-zos/6.3?topic=directives-conditional-compilation), you could [define a constant](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cobol-zos/6.3?topic=compilation-define) with a compiler directive and then...

```
    >>EVALUATE TRUE
    >>WHEN DEFINED IBM-Z
        CALL 'PBFNInit' USING                        
            BY VALUE NULL-POINTER, [...]
    >>WHEN DEFINED IBM-I
        CALL PROCEDURE 'PBFNInit' USING                        
            BY VALUE NULL-POINTER, [...]
    >>WHEN OTHER
        !non-sequiter, your facts do not coordinate
    >>END-EVALUATE
```

UPDATE 1 per comment...

You could try combining this answer with that of @SimonSobisch, something like...

```
    >>IF DEFINED IBM-I
        REPLACE ==CALL== BY ==CALL PROCEDURE==.
    >>END-IF

        CALL 'PBFNInit' USING                        
            BY VALUE NULL-POINTER, [...]
```

There is nothing currently in the documentation to indicate the text being conditionally compiled must be valid code.  Maybe the authors felt this was implicit, or maybe it's a bug.

Comment: Thank you. I have the basic conditional statement working in the code but how do I signify the DEFINE variable? I tried passing it in on the PARM statement but it says it was invalid.

Comment: I found it. In the PARM, I use something like DEFINE(IBM-Z).

Comment: I found that this isn't working for me (z/OS COBOL V6.3). While the JCL has the DEFINE(IBM-Z), the >>IF isn't accepting that as a >>DEFINE variable. So I'm still lost how to do this. :(

Comment: @EdDanley Are you getting any messages in the compile listing indicating the DEFINE is not accepted (and perhaps why)?  This could also be an indication that maintenance is needed on the compiler.  You could also try using >>DEFINE in the source, just to see if that is accepted.

Comment: (I can't figure out how to format comments.) I see Options in effect:  DEFINE(IBM-Z=B'1')    so I know the PARM was accepted on the JCL. In the COBOL compile myself, it generates the correct code for >>IF DEFINED IBM-Z but then when it gets to the >>ELSE, it also generates that code (the IBM-I call).

Comment: @EdDanley that certainly sounds like the [IF directive](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cobol-zos/6.3?topic=compilation-if) is not behaving as documented.  You might ask whomever in your shop is responsible for the COBOL compiler if IBM has a but that sounds like this.

Comment: To me the documentation reads like you must use a `>>DEFINE IBM-Z AS PARAMTER` in your COBOL-source for the compiler to pick up the `DEFINE(IBM-Z)` from the compile-option.

Comment: piet likely meant `>>DEFINE IBM-Z AS PARAMETER`  (typo, missing E).
To format in comment, just put backticks \` around your to-be-formatted-as-code

Comment: @SimonSobisch yes, of course. Glad to have a compiler check these things while programming...

Comment: As @piet.t suggested, it was the >>DEFINE IBM-Z AS PARAMTER that did the trick. Thank you all for the help. I have marked this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `WITH DEBUGGING MODE` would be a minor change in each file - but also overlap with an actual COBOL feature.

If "minor change" is ok for you then only code `CALL PROCEDURE` and use a single

`REPLACE ==CALL PROCEDURE== BY ==CALL==`.

in the source.

Comment: Actually something like what @cschneid is what I was looking for. Thanks for the suggestion however.

Comment: I think that works fine with Enterprise COBOL, but questioned that it does with COBOL for IBM/i

Answer (score 0):

If all your calls should be procedure calls, it looks like you can set this for all calls with a parameter on the compile or a process option.

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=program-identifying-linkage-type-called-programs-procedures

It says

> the LINKLIT parameter of the CRTCBLMOD and CRTBNDCBL commands, or the
> associated PROCESS statement option.
>
> The LINKLIT parameter of the CRTCBLMOD and CRTBNDCBL commands allows
> you to specify, at compile time, the linkage type for all external
> CALL literal-1, CANCEL literal-1, or SET procedure-pointer-data-item
> TO ENTRY literal-1 statements in the ILE COBOL program. You do not
> need to specify the LINKAGE TYPE clause in the SPECIAL-NAMES paragraph
> or the LINKAGE TYPE phrase with the CALL, CANCEL, or SET…ENTRY
> statement when the linkage has been defined by the LINKLIT parameter
> of CRTCBLMOD or CRTBNDCBL.

Answer (score 0):

I don't work with these compilers and don't develop infrastructure SPLs, but if I had to,  because the word PROCEDURE is the only difference for the compiler on IBM i ,   I'd do it like this

- Of course as said by piet.t  Apr. 1/2022

  DEFINE(IBM-I) as compile-option when compiling on IBM i and add   >>DEFINE IBM-I AS PARAMETER in your COBOL source (at beginning)
- Into your cobol source, just be sure to add the PROCEDURE word when needed

  ```
   CALL 
       >>IF IBM-I DEFINED 
            PROCEDURE
       >>END-IF

        'PBFNInit' USING                        
         BY VALUE NULL-POINTER, [...]
  ```